# Отключать не монитор, а только видео

Tags: windows, аудио, монитор, hdmi

В качестве звукового устройства назначен монитор, к которому подключены колонки.
Сам монитор подключен через hdmi.

В настройках Windows установлено отключение монитора через 10 минут неактивности.
Проблема в том, что при отключении монитора отключается ещё и звук.

Как перенастроить, чтобы звук не отключался?
Хочу, чтобы происходило выключение экрана, но звук продолжал воспроизводиться.

Comment: Смотреть в настройках монитора возможность разделения питания. Иначе не отключать. Не знаю, может есть сторонняя возможность в ноль убавлять яркость подсветки.

Comment: А на сайте производителя моников никаких дров или ПО не валяется?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо отключения монитора выставляете в настройках - заставка через 10 минут. В качестве заставки ставите чёрный экран, звук останется.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри ссылку [Как выключать только 1 монитор из 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378379/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-1-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-2/1379463#1379463)

С++ В этом варианте программа переводит монитор в спящий режим, скорее всего поможет. Единственное что если у тебя 2 монитора то отключаться в первом варианте будут оба.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
 

#define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
   
#define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
        
        // Скрытие консоли 

            HWND hWnd;
            AllocConsole();
            hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);

        //Нажмите ctrl + alt + 'L' для блокировки / Нажмите ctrl + 'E' для завершения программы

            while (1)
                {
                    if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
                    {
                        if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)2); //Выключение монитора 
                    }
                    if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
                    {
                        if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                            return 0;
                    }
            }
      

  
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/703336)